# Revealing module pattern and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

I have sample module like this in `module1.js` file:

```
export const Module1 = (function() {

    'use strict';

    function init()
    {
        console.log('init');
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };

}());
```

in `bootstrap.js` file I have:

```
require('./module1');
```

and in `app.js` I use:

```
require('./boostrap');

$(function() {
    Module1.init();
});
```

but I'm getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Module1 is not defined

The same is when I try to launch just:

```
Module1.init();
```

in `bootstrap.js`

Just in case - I'm not JavaScript guy, so please explain me step by step what is wrong here if fancy solution is needed. I use [Laravel mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) under the hood for webpack, I don't use any custom configuration for webpack.

Comment: Just `require`ing isn't enough - the file that's using an import needs to explicitly import it from somewhere, and that place it's imported from also needs to explicitly import it from somewhere, etc, up to the start of the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying different scenarios and it seems solution was doing it like this:

```
const Module1 = (function() {

    'use strict';

    function init()
    {
        console.log('init');
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };

}());

export default Module1;
```

And then in `bootstrap.js` including it like this:

```
import Module1 from './module1';
```

and in `bootstrap.js` I can run:

```
Module1.init();
```

However it doesn't make `Module1.init()` will work in `app.js` so I finnaly I removed this import from `boostrap.js` and now my `app.js` looks like this:

```
require('./boostrap');
import Module1 from './module1';

$(function() {
    Module1.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`require` in Javascript does not work like some other languages do. It does not import the code, but the module.

Let's take the 3 modules you have : Module1, Bootstrap, and App.

Bootstrap requires Module1, which works since you *exported* the module in the file module1.js :

```
export const Module1 = [...]
```

However, the file bootstrap.js is only exporting the module Bootstrap. It does not exports Module1.

You have to import Module1 in app.js in order to use it.

Comment: As I mentioned in question `Module1.init()` doesn't work also when it's just launched in `bootstrap.js` file

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that part. As I said (sorry if it wasn't clear), `require` imports the module. You need to store it in a variable. Replace `require('./module1');` with something like `var Module1 = require('./module1');`. Or, since you are using ES6 imports, you can use `import Module1 from './module1'`. You might want to change `export` to `export default` in module1.js if you still have an error.

Comment: I was trying this but it didn't work either when using `var Module1 = require('./module1');` I've finished with solution I've aded into answer